# Prevent SMS from being classified as spam on Android

Tags: sms, spam

One-time-password SMS send during MFA by our system is classified by Android OS as spam. Is there anything that can be done to prevent that from happening? How does Android OS determine what SMS is spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android (the OS) doesn't have internal spam detection. Instead, **it's a feature incorporated into messaging apps, and the procedure to detect spam and remove it may vary.**

For example:

- [Google Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) only provides reporting the message as not spam while the detection itself is based on machine learning models on the user's device, as per [Your chats stay private with spam detection](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9327903#zippy=%2Chow-we-protect-your-data%2Chow-spam-detection-works).

  > How spam detection works
  >
  > > Messages tries to detect suspected spam and hides it in the spam folder. If you get a suspected spam warning in Messages, you can let Google know if it’s spam or not by tapping “Report spam” or “Report not spam.”
  >
  > How we protect your data
  >
  > > [...]
  > >
  > > When Spam protection is on, Messages uses machine learning models that operate on your device to detect known spam patterns in your messages. The app analyzes these patterns to catch more spam and warn you sooner. Because spam is detected on-device, Messages warns you about spam even when you don’t have a data connection.
  > >
  > > [...]
- [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller) relies on user's contribution but allows for manual appeal, as mentioned in their FAQ, [What is spam?](https://support.truecaller.com/support/solutions/articles/81000392568-what-is-spam)

  > Truecaller spam lists are created by our user community who choose to report unsolicited calls and SMS messages.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > We acknowledge that mistakes can happen from time to time.  If you believe that your number has been mistakenly added to our spam list, for the **EU, EEA, and Switzerland** please [email to support.eu@truecaller.com]. For the **rest of the world** please [email to support@truecaller.com].
- For other messaging apps, please search for their own help center, support, or policy.